# Unable to set canvas height AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, canvas, resize

So I have a canvas element and I want to draw a chart using Angular library. I manage to draw it but the problem is that the canvas element does not take the height of the containing div, it takes a random height. Has anybody had this problem before ? I also used the resize() method from the ChartJs library (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) but it does not seem to work. Does anybody have an idea ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @blaa, is it possible to provide us with a codepen? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the default values.

```
// Boolean - whether or not the chart should be responsive and resize when the browser does.
responsive: true,
// Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when     responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
maintainAspectRatio: false
```

Read more at : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-global-configuration

Comment: i changed the default settings but it does not work. It does not maintain  the height of the container

Comment: Is it possible to add a codepen so we can have a closer look at the exact problem?